# Textfield recognition of code

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I am creating an app that will all users to write code. I want to create a textfield that will recognize code being put into it and color code the code correctly. [repl.it](http://repl.it) is a website that has a similar function to what I am looking for. I only want the code to be color coded, I do not need the code to run or build. I have searched everywhere online for answer or reference but I have not found anything. Ultimately I want to allow a user to select a language(java, Swift, Python, etc.) and be able to write code in that language. Any references or answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should use regular expressions to check if the user is entering a certain type of expressions corresponding to a programmation language. It's something similar as BBCode I think.

Comment: You can show web code editor in a webview as they provide rich functionality om code formatting and styling. You have to write use some parsing library or look at syntax highlighter library and implement that to have the same functionality in UITextField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want to build an app for code highlighting.
Setting it up is quite an intensive process. You need to build something like a Lexical Analyzer for many languages, or setup a lot of RegEx.

If you want to go ahead with that then good luck, but if you just want to make a simple app in a short time I think you would be better off using a library. Take this one for example...

https://github.com/raspu/Highlightr

> Highlightr is an iOS & macOS syntax highlighter built with Swift. It uses highlight.js as it core, supports 169 languages and comes with 77 styles.

If you want to give it your own look then just fork it and modify, better than single-handedly setting up the core for syntax highlighting.

Comment: Do you know of any tutorials or guides on how to integrate it into an app?

Answer (score 0):

First, you start by having a UITextField with an attributedText.

Then you setup a delegate for that textfield and listen for the `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` function.
This one is called whenever the user types something or pastes code into the textfield.

Inside you look (if its just one single character which has been put in) for a delimiter being typed. Then you traverse the string from there on backwards until you find the next delimiter.

This being done, you apply a function on that specific range of the code to replace its content with an attributed string version, which has the right color applied.
(E.g. this method could be used: `addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey, value: Any, range: NSRange)` on `NSMutableAttributedString`)

As suggested in the comments the colouring function could be done with a regular expression search.

For example a basic
`getMatches(in originalString: String, using pattern: String) -> [Range<String.Index>]` or
`getMatches(in originalString: String, using pattern: String) -> [String]` would do the job.

```
var matches: [String] = []
var temp = originalString

while true {
    if let match = temp.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) {

        matches.append(temp.substring(with: match))
        temp.removeSubrange(match)
    } else {
        break
    }
}
```

The variable `pattern` is your regular expression. A good way to try it out 
is available here: [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com)